# SUMPRODUCT if two conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a formula in excel that returns the sum of a product of two columns in a range, based on a greater than value. Specifically, if any row in column E is a given number and any row in column H is > 0, multiply column F and G and sum these products. Excel gives me a value of 0 with the formula below, but I want it to give me 225.

```
=IF(AND(shipping_logs!H2:H999999>0,shipping_logs!E2:E998940="395078"),
(SUMPRODUCT(shipping_logs!F2:F999999,shipping_logs!G2:G999999)),0)
```

Column G and H can have negative values, so the formula also needs to max at 0. If the sum of the products is a negative value, I want it to give me 0, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..

[image]

Comment: Are you really going to run [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) through almost a million rows of data? How large is your actual data?

Answer (score 2):

You only want to use the minimum number of rows possible with a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff). That makes a formula *look* complicated, but it isn't really.

Pick one of the important columns, preferably with numbers. Either column F or G will do. To find the last row containing a number you can use,

```
=MATCH(1e99, F:F)
```

Even if there is something below the last number, it is not important since we only want the numbers.

Your SUMPRODUCT formula is now,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((sl!E2:INDEX(sl!E:E, MATCH(1E+99, sl!F:F))=395078)*
            (sl!G2:INDEX(sl!G:G, MATCH(1E+99, sl!F:F))>0)*
            (sl!H2:INDEX(sl!H:H, MATCH(1E+99, sl!F:F))>0),
             sl!F2:INDEX(sl!F:F, MATCH(1E+99, sl!F:F)),
             sl!G2:INDEX(sl!G:G, MATCH(1E+99, sl!F:F)))
```

A ballpark guess would that the formula will be causing noticeable calculation lag if the ranges of cells exceed 2-3 thousand.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot see how 225 fits into the scheme of things without seeing sample data.

Comment: Sorry I should have place an image in my original post. I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

One of your formula for checking if any row in column E is a given number is wrong. Try using any of the following formula instead.

=IF(AND(shipping_logs!H2:H999999>0,(CountIF(shipping_logs!E2:E998940,395078)),
(SUMPRODUCT(shipping_logs!F2:F999999,shipping_logs!G2:G999999)),0)

=IF(AND(shipping_logs!H2:H999999>0,(ISNUMBER(MATCH(395078,shipping_logs!E2:E998940))),
(SUMPRODUCT(shipping_logs!F2:F999999,shipping_logs!G2:G999999)),0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative I was working on:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(shipping_logs!F2:INDEX(shipping_logs!F:F,COUNTA(shipping_logs!F:F)),
            shipping_logs!G2:INDEX(shipping_logs!G:G,COUNTA(shipping_logs!G:G)),
            --(shipping_logs!E2:INDEX(shipping_logs!E:E,COUNTA(shipping_logs!E:E))=395078),
            --(shipping_logs!H2:INDEX(shipping_logs!H:H,COUNTA(shipping_logs!H:H))>0))
```